Negative eigenvalue in PSD sum of matrices
Suppose that $A+B$ is positive semidefinite. Then the sum of the two matrices has only nonnegative eigenvalues. I want to prove that, given $B$ is of rank $1$, $A$ has at most $1$ negative eigenvalue, as I'm having trouble seeing this.
Could anybody kindly help me?
P.S: I encountered this in a paper on spectral graph theory.

It is straightforward to construct a simple diagonal counterexample.

Do you mean $A$ has at most one negative eigenvalue?

$B = vu^T$ where $|u| = 1$. Then consider an orthonormal basis $u, u_2, \dots, u_n$.

The claim does not hold in general. Let $$A+B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 10 
\end{pmatrix},\quad B=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 9\\ -2 & 18 
\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $B$ has rank $1$ and
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -9\\ 2 & -8 
\end{pmatrix}$$ The matrix $A$ has two negative eigenvalues $-3\pm \sqrt{7}.$
The claim holds if the matrix $A$ is symmetric, i.e. $A$ admits at most one (up to a constant multiple) eigenvector corresponding to a negative eigenvalue. Assume for a contradiction that $A$ admits two linearly independent eigenvectors $v,w$   corresponding to negative eigenvalues. If the eigenvalues are different then $v\perp w$ due to the symmetry of $A.$ If $v,w$ correspond to one eigenvalue WLOG we may assume $v\perp w.$ Then $\langle Av,w\rangle =\langle Aw,v\rangle =0$ and for any coefficients $\alpha,\beta,$ $\alpha^2+\beta^2\neq 0,$ we get $$\langle A(\alpha v+\beta w),\alpha v+\beta w\rangle=\alpha^2\langle Av,v\rangle +\beta^2\langle Aw,w\rangle <0$$
Since $B$ is one dimensional there is $ u:=\alpha v+\beta w\neq 0,$ such that $Bu=0.$ Then
$$\langle (A+B)u,u\rangle=\langle Au,u\rangle<0 $$
a contradiction.
